# Разработка под android на C#

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

Какие существуют способы разработки под android на С# кроме xamarin?

Comment: Да, Unity......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В принципе проверенных альтернатив нет. //PS не мобильный разработчик

- Xamarin - отHelloWord'ил - вполне жизнеспособно.
- Unity - Если aepot говорит что Unity есть - значит что-то на нём написать точно можно.
- Avalonia - если верить левым источникам - мертворождённая Avalonia как-то может.
- MAUI - Грядущий фреймворк от мелкософта, который сейчас в бете вместе с .NET 6 должен.
- Uno Platform - базируется на библиотеке Skia, и выглядит как браузер в коробке, тем самым обеспечивая 100% кроссплатформенность, куда более перспективнее чем Avalonia (на мой личный взгляд).

Comment: Еще нужно заметить, что MAUI со временем заменит Xamarin по планам майкрософт, предположительно через год после релиза